# Show 1st 2 characters in purejs from the class and hide the rest

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show the first 2 letters i.e., `En`. 
I want to use Pure JS to finish this.
There is no changes whatsoever. I have tried to add the JS in both header and footer, still no change on the site.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="myclassname">English</a>
```

**JS:**

```
var i;
var sheb = document.getElementsByClassName("myclassname");
for(i=0;i<sheb.length;i++) {
  if(sheb[i].className == 'myclass') {
    sheb[i].innerHTML = sheb[i].innerHTML.substring(0,3);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `divs`?

Comment: @Mamun Edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

There is a mismatch between the class name used in HTML (`myclassname`) and in JavaScript (`myclass`).

Then your are taking up to 3 character with `.substring(0,3)`. Here the second argument (`3`) is the length to take from the string. You have to change that to `.substring(0,2)`.

Try the following way:

```js
var i;
var sheb = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
for(i=0;i<sheb.length;i++) {
  if(sheb[i].className == 'myclass') {
    sheb[i].innerHTML = sheb[i].innerHTML.substring(0,2);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="myclass">English</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your `if` statement; you check if the className is `myclass` instead of `myclassname`.
Also, you should use `substring(0,2)` instead of `substring(0,3)`.

Apart from those 2 mistakes, it works fine:

```js
var i;
var sheb = document.getElementsByClassName("myclassname");
for(i=0;i<sheb.length;i++) {
  if(sheb[i].className == 'myclassname') {
   sheb[i].innerHTML = sheb[i].innerHTML.substring(0,2);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="myclassname">English</a>
```